# Sum of series less than epsilon

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $x=(x_k) $ be a sequence such that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{ x_k}{\rho} < \infty$, for some $\rho>0$ and let $\lambda =(\lambda_i)$ be a sequence with $\lambda_i \rightarrow 0$. 
Define
 $\displaystyle g(x) = \inf\left\{ \rho : \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ x_k}{\rho} \leqslant 
1, \right\}$. Prove that $g(\lambda_i x) \rightarrow 0$ as $\lambda_i \rightarrow 0$.

In proof, they shown that $\forall \varepsilon >0$, there exists positive integer $m$ 
such that 
 $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \lambda_i x_k}{\rho} <\varepsilon~for~ 
i\geqslant m$. How this implies $g(\lambda_i x) \rightarrow 0$ as $\lambda_i 
\rightarrow 0$ ?.

Comment: The $\rho$ seems unnecessary.  As you've defined it, $g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k.$  Is there a typo?

Comment: Sorry that's not a typing mistake. This problem is related to Orlicz sequence space and I have assumed identity function for Orlicz function.

Comment: All right.  Do you want the answer to work for more general Orlicz functions?  If you are okay with it only working for linear Orlicz functions (as with the identity function) then $g$ is linear and $g(\lambda_i x) = \lambda_i g(x)$ obviously goes to $0$ as $\lambda_i \to 0$, and the reason the step in question holds is basically just the definition of the limit.

Answer (score 0):

If $i \geq m$ then $\epsilon \rho$ is an element of the set whose infimum is $g(\lambda_ix)$. Hence $g(\lambda_i x) <\epsilon \rho$ for $i \geq m$.